# Having trouble designing an architecture(schematic)

Tags: fpga, boolean-logic, cpu-architecture, digital-logic

Okay so I am currently in a Digital Logics designing class and I am stumped on a design we were asked to do this week.
We were told to Design an architecture(DataPath + control) that can perform the following functions based on a command.

Im assuming its going to be all one schematic with several prerequisites.

The 3 functions are

```
 1. Z = A + B 
 2. Z = A & B (as in like bitwise AND)
 3. Z= 1 if A < B and 0 if A > B
```

We are told to assume A and B are inputs and Z is an output and assume all inputs are 4 bits each.

2 things are confusing me. One is that if it's on the same schematic then how would it be three different functions. Wouldn't Z go high after A or B are one? and second how do you do inequalities? Would you use a series of Flip flops Like a shift register?

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a mutiplexer to select which of the three functions to output, only one function can be outputted at one time (since there is a single output), but you can select which function to execute. This requires another input to the circuit in order to control the mux.

Inequalities are dealt with a comparator. You didn't specify what tool you are using to design your circuit, but I'm guessing schematic entry. In that case, it should have comparators in its standard library.

On a side note, a greater-than comparaison is done with a subtractor, i.e. if `A-B` is negative, than `A>B`, otherwise `B>=A`.

Comment: Oh okay so im guessing ill need a 4 bit multiplexor. Okay I know how to do this! I feel pretty dumb I didnt remember that earlier. Thanks a lot for everything though!